# Scrollspy doesn't change until you get to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am working on a twitter bootstrap scrollspy navigation. Than navigation bar and everything works except one small bug the currently selected item doesn't change until you scroll to the bottom of the section. For an example of what I am talking about here is my demo page: http://pwbguild.com/test/demo.html

Scroll down the page, you'll notice it doesn't change to "About" until you get to the bottom of the section.

I know the issue is with "navbar-fixed-bottom" because if I change it to top "navbar-fixed-top" it seems to work perfectly.

Could anyone help me understand why this is changing at the bottom of the section and not the top of the section?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in IE/Chrome/Firefox. It was all jacked up using Lynx though.

Comment: So when you hit the top of the first black section the "About" button in the nav bar changes to a dark orange?

Comment: When the word "About" is at the top of the browser it changes to dark orange.

Comment: See It doesn't work on any of my five major browsers on windows 7 at all. It doesn't change until it gets to the bottom of the dark.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the Scrollspy to apply as soon as a section comes into the viewport. I suggest you to use the data-offset-tag and set it to the viewport height. Just add the following to you body-tag (which is the element you spy on):

```
data-offset="$(window).height();"
```

Your body opening tag then should look like this:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="$(window).height();" style="zoom: 1;">
```